# Having trouble finding the average of data from imported XML

Tags: python, xml, database, import, attributes

Have to find the average of net Income from XML data by importing properties.xml
then send the row from the database with the average net Income to the key dictionary.
When I use the formula in the average income function nothing prints out. Even if I try to print it out straight from the function before sending it to the dictionary.

```
from helper import fixNumber
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("properties.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

list = []

for child in root:
    data = child.attrib.copy()
    data['netIncome'] = fixNumber(child.text)
    data["id"] = (data["id"])
    data['cost'] = fixNumber(data['cost'])
    data['downPayment'] = fixNumber(data['downPayment'])
    data['state'] = (data['state'])
    data['percentage'] = fixNumber(data['percentage'])
    list.append(data)

def average_income(data):
    return data['netIncome']


average = sum(data['netIncome']) / len(data['netIncome'])

print(average)
```

Then have to send a row from data with the average net income to this dictionary

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_func = {
        5: average_income
     }

    for key in my_func:
        funct = my_func[key]
        print(f"{key}", funct(data))
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/VisualStudio/01.LESSON/properties.py", line 34, in <module>
    average = sum(data['netIncome']) / len(data['netIncome'])
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

This is a sample of the properties.xml being called in the code

```
<properties>
    <property id="H00001" cost="106000"  downPayment="24380" state="NM" percentage="0.12">2925.6</property>
    <property id="H00002" cost="125000"  downPayment="30000" state="AZ" percentage="0.15">4500</property>
    <property id="H00003" cost="119000"  downPayment="24990" state="NH" percentage="0.13">3248.7</property>
    <property id="H00004" cost="124000"  downPayment="31000" state="MI" percentage="0.19">5890</property>
    <property id="H00005" cost="143000"  downPayment="34320" state="CZ" percentage="0.11">3775.2</property>
    <property id="H00006" cost="139000"  downPayment="30580" state="VI" percentage="0.12">3669.6</property>
    <property id="H00007" cost="132000"  downPayment="26400" state="ND" percentage="0.19">5016</property>
    <property id="H00008" cost="134000"  downPayment="26800" state="CZ" percentage="0.17">4556</property>
    <property id="H00009" cost="143000"  downPayment="34320" state="PA" percentage="0.14">4804.8</property>
    <property id="H00010" cost="123000"  downPayment="25830" state="IN" percentage="0.2">5166</property>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your average to use the list you create instead of using the variable from the for loop:

```py
from helper import fixNumber
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("properties.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

data_list = []

for child in root:
    data = child.attrib.copy()
    data['netIncome'] = fixNumber(child.text)
    data["id"] = (data["id"])
    data['cost'] = fixNumber(data['cost'])
    data['downPayment'] = fixNumber(data['downPayment'])
    data['state'] = (data['state'])
    data['percentage'] = fixNumber(data['percentage'])
    data_list.append(data)

average = sum([i['netIncome'] for i in data_list]) / len(data_list)

print(average)
```

I also renamed the list to data_list to prevent shadowing the builtin list keyword.

This also assumes that your `fixNumber` function returns either `int` or `float`.